# Round numbers in dataset

Tags: python, dataset

How do I round all numbers in the following dataset to two decimals?

Data: (made with `sklearn.datasets.make_classification`)

```
(array([[  9.51473798e+00,   1.06087194e+00,   2.06821090e+00],
   [  1.08111941e+01,  -1.17318038e+00,   1.92456800e+00],
   [  9.54325568e+00,  -2.63283088e+00,   1.83071683e+00],
   [  1.01557058e+01,   1.34472565e+00,   2.08646185e+00],
   [  1.01752715e+01,  -1.58531347e+00,   1.89806907e+00],
   [  1.02821146e+01,   1.30596456e-01,   2.00839696e+00],
   [  1.11813747e+01,   3.12248279e-01,   2.02007663e+00],
   [  8.70831483e+00,   1.27855093e-01,   2.00822070e+00],
   [  1.04586755e+01,   9.12573259e-01,   2.05867574e+00],
   [  1.07756665e+01,   1.15780378e+00,   2.07444333e+00],
   [  8.48514084e+00,   2.47297775e+00,   2.15900509e+00],
   [  1.00588091e+01,   1.87746158e+00,   2.12071518e+00],
   [  9.73621491e+00,  -1.66534221e+00,   1.89292346e+00],
   [  9.93346654e+00,   2.60968551e-01,   2.01677950e+00],
   [  8.99640622e+00,   7.62727748e-01,   2.04904112e+00],
   [  1.00017181e+01,  -4.33039874e-01,   1.97215683e+00],
   [  1.05397822e+01,   8.42973876e-03,   2.00054201e+00],
   [  1.07544789e+01,   4.09195812e-01,   2.02631007e+00],
   [  8.89519175e+00,  -1.35440590e-01,   1.99129157e+00],
   [  9.99620790e+00,   1.37789288e+00,   2.08859440e+00],
   [  1.03346610e+01,  -1.12155564e+00,   1.92788732e+00],
   [  9.39991001e+00,   6.21842011e-01,   2.03998259e+00],
   [  9.77006674e+00,   3.42934624e-02,   2.00220497e+00],
   [  1.02332133e+01,   2.48219280e-01,   2.01595976e+00],
   [  7.55815579e+00,   1.88355653e+00,   2.12110706e+00],
   [  1.05768829e+01,   6.55770500e-01,   2.04216409e+00],
   [  9.27815497e+00,  -6.45278769e-01,   1.95851050e+00],
   [  1.04151788e+01,   6.97132320e-01,   2.04482353e+00],
   [  1.15131177e+01,  -2.40639236e+00,   1.84527615e+00],
   [  9.08421360e+00,  -2.19164450e+00,   1.85908380e+00],
   [  7.99416204e+00,  -1.75595979e+00,   1.88709702e+00],
   [  8.56267102e+00,   9.84055929e-01,   2.06327186e+00],
   [  1.04842929e+01,   1.29745037e+00,   2.08342219e+00],
   [  1.02405219e+01,  -1.69821092e+00,   1.89081010e+00],
   [  1.18692596e+01,  -4.25146800e-01,   1.97266433e+00],
   [  1.06133133e+01,   1.34378970e+00,   2.08640167e+00],
   [  9.57509601e+00,  -2.01072871e-01,   1.98707161e+00],
   [  1.12107856e+01,   3.88585794e-01,   2.02498491e+00],
   [  1.07286567e+01,  -1.35610478e+00,   1.91280651e+00],
   [  1.03395804e+01,  -2.21662042e+00,   1.85747792e+00],
   [  1.12811073e+01,   6.80546943e-01,   2.04375714e+00],
   [  8.88072513e+00,  -1.60724337e+00,   1.89665905e+00],
   [  1.07451042e+01,   9.86592073e-02,   2.00634349e+00],
   [  8.57993952e+00,   1.41471786e+00,   2.09096214e+00],
   [  1.08589694e+01,   2.82687166e-01,   2.01817594e+00],
   [  1.12506257e+01,   2.08290126e+00,   2.13392434e+00],
   [  9.07650741e+00,  -1.99937066e+00,   1.87144643e+00],
   [  9.18217127e+00,   1.05595704e+00,   2.06789489e+00],
   [  9.83923951e+00,   6.74214387e-01,   2.04334997e+00],
   [  1.10189161e+01,  -1.57111750e+00,   1.89898183e+00],
   [  1.11232398e+01,   1.24406595e+00,   2.07998973e+00],
   [  1.17818899e+01,   8.01620091e-01,   2.05154178e+00],
   [  1.00545554e+01,  -1.21645214e+00,   1.92178576e+00],
   [  1.07055616e+01,  -1.00538364e+00,   1.93535683e+00],
   [  1.01627173e+01,   9.08204290e-01,   2.05839483e+00],
   [  1.11346109e+01,  -9.82710730e-01,   1.93681463e+00],
   [  9.88492991e+00,   8.66479536e-01,   2.05571205e+00],
   [  9.50910952e+00,   7.88704893e-01,   2.05071137e+00],
   [  9.61461851e+00,   1.80032081e+00,   2.11575526e+00],
   [  9.77216178e+00,   1.96949357e+00,   2.12663256e+00],
   [  8.34266830e+00,  -2.49499499e+00,   1.83957927e+00],
   [  1.08865287e+01,   6.55672331e-01,   2.04215777e+00],
   [  1.14447138e+01,  -2.41611886e+00,   1.84465077e+00],
   [  1.05451701e+01,  -1.07142045e+00,   1.93111086e+00],
   [  9.19567423e+00,   2.73418131e-02,   2.00175800e+00],
   [  8.92932563e+00,   1.07317193e+00,   2.06900175e+00],
   [  1.16406170e+01,   8.03768290e-01,   2.05167990e+00],
   [  1.00164697e+01,  -1.98874360e-01,   1.98721297e+00],
   [  9.53515005e+00,  -1.58545347e+00,   1.89806007e+00],
   [  9.52769059e+00,  -9.99807077e-01,   1.93571539e+00],
   [  1.05248201e+01,   5.50033548e-01,   2.03536552e+00],
   [  8.52606936e+00,  -1.19208469e+00,   1.92335251e+00],
   [  1.11653915e+01,   1.33731762e+00,   2.08598553e+00],
   [  9.90589378e+00,   7.48002479e-01,   2.04809433e+00],
   [  9.96470477e+00,  -2.46452626e+00,   1.84153831e+00],
   [  1.05303612e+01,   1.35638329e+00,   2.08721140e+00],
   [  1.08745135e+01,  -3.62251680e+00,   1.76708298e+00],
   [  9.61493323e+00,   1.43721577e+00,   2.09240869e+00],
   [  8.57327004e+00,   5.62364661e-01,   2.03615837e+00],
   [  9.49368312e+00,  -1.80383458e+00,   1.88401882e+00],
   [  9.33754206e+00,   2.16505300e+00,   2.13920645e+00],
   [  1.05894191e+01,  -3.69555466e-02,   1.99762387e+00],
   [  1.07728886e+01,  -1.18528532e+00,   1.92378969e+00],
   [  9.40721298e+00,   1.14763583e+00,   2.07378956e+00],
   [  1.08594792e+01,  -2.32332937e-01,   1.98506169e+00],
   [  8.60823925e+00,  -1.73226676e+00,   1.88862042e+00],
   [  1.00985383e+01,  -6.19572821e-01,   1.96016332e+00],
   [  1.01875246e+01,  -1.37696632e+00,   1.91146517e+00],
   [  9.15065626e+00,  -1.13415418e+00,   1.92707727e+00],
   [  1.15413575e+01,  -1.84399356e+00,   1.88143672e+00],
   [  8.71159033e+00,   1.15187491e+00,   2.07406212e+00],
   [  8.02709487e+00,   1.29694811e+00,   2.08338989e+00],
   [  1.06796162e+01,  -4.23630647e-02,   1.99727618e+00],
   [  8.34784789e+00,  -1.34144413e+00,   1.91374914e+00],
   [  9.67722225e+00,   9.88166115e-01,   2.06353613e+00],
   [  9.31050778e+00,  -4.41839726e-01,   1.97159102e+00],
   [  8.98615397e+00,  -3.68074713e-01,   1.97633389e+00],
   [  1.17489503e+01,  -1.68424747e+00,   1.89170791e+00],
   [  1.13052365e+01,  -2.38585027e+00,   1.84659695e+00],
   [  1.09864258e+01,   1.07100435e+00,   2.06886238e+00]]), array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in a typical variable named *var*, do the following:

```
[np.round(item) for item in var[0]]
```

Because *numpy* is vectorised, you can simply use the following code which its result is as above:

```
np.round(var[0])
```

which will get you the rounded array. Consider that you can specify the number of decimal points using `decimals` in the argument list of `round` function.

Comment: Default rounding is to 0 decimal places, so you need to specify `np.round(item, decimals=2)`

Comment: Yes, I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

You have a *tuple* of two numpy arrays, I'll call it `your_tuple`.

To round all values in each array to 2 decimal places:

```
rounded_arrays = [np.round(each_arr, decimals=2) for each_arr in your_tuple]
```

The result is a `list` holding your two arrays. If you want them back in a tuple, just do this:

```
result = tuple(rounded_arrays)
```

---

Only the first array has decimal points, so rounding the second array won't have any effect.

Also, have a look here for [differences between lists and tuples](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/).